# Is there a way to execute a python script inside a vb program

Tags: python, vb6

I have tried to search for tutorials nothing exists is it even possible if yes how.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbfaq/archive/2004/05/30/144573.aspx  top link from googling "vb execute other program"

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`Shell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242087%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) function to execute `"python.exe yourscript.py"`.  Note that this assumes python.exe is in your PATH. Otherwise, use the full path to python, usually c:\Python27